# vim change one occurrence alone in the line

Tags: vim

I had a text like this

```
pid_t child;
long orig_eax;
child = fork();
if(child == 0) {
    printf("the child is happy %d", child);
    printf("the child");
```

I wanted to replace the word 'child' selectively using vim
so I used

> %s/child/pid/c

so it asked me before replacing each match
but when it came to line 5 where there are two occurrences of 'child' , where I wanted to replace second one alone , so when it prompted to change first occurrence I gave 'n' , then instead asking the next occurrence in the same line it skipped the entire line and went to the next line.

Is this the expected behavior  ?

If so how to ignore the first occurrence in the line but replace the second in the same line using the above search command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `g` ('global') modifier after the second `/` (along with the `c` (which stands for 'confirm')) : `:%s/child/pid/cg`

For more informations on flags, have a look at `:help s_flags`.

For instance, for the `g` flag :

```
[g]     Replace all occurrences in the line.  Without this argument,
        replacement occurs only for the first occurrence in each line.  If
        the 'edcompatible' option is on, Vim remembers this flag and toggles
        it each time you use it, but resets it when you give a new search
        pattern.  If the 'gdefault' option is on, this flag is on by default
        and the [g] argument switches it off.
```

Comment: I did not know about this combination .. Thanks .. that solves problem

Comment: If you find it hard to adapt to that, you can also `:set gdefault` to toggle the default.